# JUnit4 run all tests in a specific package using a testsuite

Tags: java, junit, junit4, test-suite

Is this possible in JUnit4?

In JUnit3, I would do the following:

```
public class MyTestSuite {

  public static Test suite() throws Exception {
     doBeforeActions();

     try {
        TestSuite testSuite = new TestSuite();
        for(Class clazz : getAllClassesInPackage("com.mypackage")){
            testSuite.addTestSuite(clazz);
        }
        return testSuite;
     } finally {
        doAfterActions
     }
  }

...

}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with junit4?

Comment: @bbaja42 I don't want to run this with junit4, I want to use the junit4 annotations for my tests and run all of them using a testsuite.

Comment: An "actual" answer to this question would be nice.  Somehow, Eclipse is able to accomplish this by clicking one little checkbox in the JUnit run configuration panel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The takari-cpsuite](https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite) (originally developed by [Johannes Link](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.html)) offers a classpath-suite which should fit your needs.
It allows filtering of classes in the Classpath by regular expressions like:

```
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite.*;
...
@ClassnameFilters({"mytests.*", ".*Test"})
public class MySuite...
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use JUnitToolBox:

```
@RunWith(WildcardPatternSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses("**/*Test.class")
public class MySuite {
}
```

Maven config:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.googlecode.junit-toolbox</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-toolbox</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

see https://code.google.com/p/junit-toolbox/ for more details.

Comment: Tried this, but doesn't work I keep getting "failed to scan..." error.

Comment: It can only scan packages in his folder and subfolder. So you need to create an AllTestSuite in com.[yourCompany].

By the way. This configuration  ("**/*Test.class") assumes that all your test classes end in "Test".

Comment: Beware it doesn't work if the test is packaged in a jar. There is a open request to solve this. https://code.google.com/p/junit-toolbox/issues/detail?id=2