# How to create a JUnit TestSuite thats loads the tests from a package or folder?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, test-suite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JUnit4 run all tests in a specific package using a testsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331214/junit4-run-all-tests-in-a-specific-package-using-a-testsuite)

i need to create a JUnit(4) TestSuite that is able to load the test classes at runtime.
I have a changing amount of tests inside a package and i do not want to add all of them to the test suite by hand (@SuiteClasses).

Does anyone knows a way to do this inside the suite class?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331214/junit4-run-all-tests-in-a-specific-package-using-a-testsuite/7565080#7565080